# seqMD: size of substitution cost matrix

Tags: sequence, traminer

I'm conducting a multichannel sequence analysis with 3 channels, for which I have defined three separate substitution cost matrices as the basis for Optimal Matching.

I get the following error message, when using `seqMD`:

```
 > MDcost <- seqMD(channels, method = OM, sm=smatrix, what="cost", norm = "auto", 
 +                 indel = "auto", with.missing = TRUE)
  [!!] 3  domains with  288  sequences
  [>] building MD sequences of combined states... OK
  [>] including missing value as an additional state
  [>] checking 'sm' (size and triangle inequality)
 Error:  [!] size of substitution cost matrix must be 8x8
```

The substitution cost matrix for the first channel is 7x7. I assume the error is related to this message in the output:
`including missing value as an additional state`
But there are no missings in my channels. I used `seqdef` with `left = DEL` for sequences in each channel as my sequences are of varying length across my units.

I have no issues when using `seqdist` for the monochannels:

```
> ch1.dist.OM.th <- seqdist(ch1.seq, method = "OM", indel = "auto",
+                           sm = ch1.sub.th, norm = "auto")
 [>] 288 sequences with 7 distinct states
 [>] checking 'sm' (size and triangle inequality)
 [>] 265 distinct  sequences 
 [>] min/max sequence lengths: 2/48
 [>] computing distances using the OM maxlength normalized metric
 [>] elapsed time: 0.052 secs
```

Here, there is no indication of missing values/added states and the substitution matrices work fine. I'm grateful for any hints to solve this problem.

23-03-02 UPDATE
Here is the output for three UoO for the 3 channels

```
> MDseq <- seqMD(channels)
 [!!] 3  domains with  3  sequences
 [>] building MD sequences of combined states... OK
> seqlength(MDseq)
  Length
1     31
2     18
3     17
> MDseq
  Sequence                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
1 P09+R00+G00-P09+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-
P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-
P07+R05+G00-P07+R05+G00-P07+R05+G00-P07+R05+G00-P07+R05+G00-P07+R05+G00-
P07+R04+G00-P07+R04+G00-P07+R04+G00-P07+R04+G00-P07+R04+G00-P07+R03+G00-
P07+R03+G00-P07+R03+G00-P07+R03+G00-P07+R05+G02-P04+R05+G02-P04+R05+G02-
P04+R05+G02
2 P09+R00+G00-P09+R00+G00-P09+R00+G00-P05+R00+G00-P05+R14+G00-P05+R10+G00-
P05+R10+G00-P05+R10+G00-P05+R10+G00-P05+R10+G00-P05+R09+G00-P05+R09+G00-
P05+R09+G00-P05+R09+G00-P05+R04+G00-P05+R05+G00-P05+R05+G00-P04+R04+G00
3 P09+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-P07+R00+G00-
P07+R11+G00-P07+R11+G05-P07+R11+G05-P07+R11+G05-P05+R11+G05-P05+R08+G00-
P05+R08+G00-P04+R08+G00-P04+R08+G00-P04+R08+G00-P04+R08+G00
> seqstatl(MDseq)
 [1] "%"           "P04+R04+G00" "P04+R05+G02" "P04+R08+G00" "P05+R00+G00"
 [6] "P05+R04+G00" "P05+R05+G00" "P05+R08+G00" "P05+R09+G00" "P05+R10+G00"
[11] "P05+R11+G05" "P05+R14+G00" "P07+R00+G00" "P07+R03+G00" "P07+R04+G00"
[16] "P07+R05+G00" "P07+R05+G02" "P07+R11+G00" "P07+R11+G05" "P09+R00+G00"
> MDcost <- seqMD(channels, method = OM, sm=smatrix, what="cost", norm = "auto", 
+                 indel = "auto")
 [!!] 3  domains with  3  sequences
 [>] building MD sequences of combined states... OK
 [>] including missing value as an additional state
 [>] checking 'sm' (size and triangle inequality)
Error:  [!] size of substitution cost matrix must be 8x8
> smatrix[[1]]
    P04 P05 P06 P07 P08 P09 P00
P04   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
P05   1   0   1   2   3   4   5
P06   2   1   0   1   2   3   4
P07   3   2   1   0   1   2   3
P08   4   3   2   1   0   1   2
P09   5   4   3   2   1   0   1
P00   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
```

Comment: If there are no missing, why are you setting `with.missing=TRUE`?

Comment: I was unsure about `with.missing`. Now I think I misunderstood the description given here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TraMineR/versions/2.0-8/topics/seqdistmc
The sequences vary in length between my units, but not between channels within my units.
However, I get the same error message without this parameter.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example (2 or 3 sequences) generating the error.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for looking into this problem. I have updated my original post to include the output for 3 UoO.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `seqMD`. I cannot run your example because you do not provide the data. However, I think I have identified the issue. The error occurs because of a badly specified test in `seqMD`, which sets `with.missing` as `TRUE` when sequences do not all have the same length as in your data.

This will be fixed within two days in the development version available on [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=743) (now released as v 2.2-7 on the CRAN).

In the meantime, the only workaround I see is to make all sequences of the same length by setting right missings as true missings, i.e., by specifying `right=NA` in the `seqdef` commands. I illustrate below with a small example:

```
ch <- read.table(header=FALSE,text="
                    n n n n c c c c
                    n n c c c c c c
                    n n n n n c c c
                 ")
ch[3,7:8] <- NA


work <- read.table(header=FALSE,text="
                    u w w u u u w w
                    u u u u w w w w
                    w w w u u u w w
                 ")

## turning last two elements of 3rd sequence to NA
work[3,7:8] <- NA

## sequence objects
s.ch <- seqdef(ch, cpal=c("yellow","blue"), right=NA)
s.work <- seqdef(work, cpal=c("pink","green"), right=NA)
```

Now we run `seqMD`, first to show the multidomain (MD) sequences, and then to compute CAT costs:

```
## multidomain sequences
seqMD(list(s.ch,s.work)) 
#   Sequence                       
# 1 n+u-n+w-n+w-n+u-c+u-c+u-c+w-c+w
# 2 n+u-n+u-c+u-c+u-c+w-c+w-c+w-c+w
# 3 n+w-n+w-n+w-n+u-n+u-c+u-*+*-*+*      

## costs for each of the two channels
cost.ch <- seqcost(s.ch,method="INDELSLOG", with.missing=TRUE)
cost.work <- seqcost(s.work,method="INDELSLOG", with.missing=TRUE)

## CAT costs
seqMD(list(s.ch,s.work), sm=list(cost.ch$sm,cost.work$sm), 
      indel=list(cost.ch$indel,cost.work$indel), what="cost", 
      with.missing=c(TRUE,TRUE))
#          *+*       c+u       c+w       n+u       n+w
# *+* 0.000000 1.8579148 1.8579148 1.8579148 1.8579148
# c+u 1.857915 0.0000000 0.6317059 0.6317059 1.2634118
# c+w 1.857915 0.6317059 0.0000000 1.2634118 0.6317059
# n+u 1.857915 0.6317059 1.2634118 0.0000000 0.6317059
# n+w 1.857915 1.2634118 0.6317059 0.6317059 0.0000000
# attr(,"indel")
# [1] 1.2262089 0.6317059 0.6317059 0.6317059 0.6317059
# attr(,"alphabet")
# [1] "*+*" "c+u" "c+w" "n+u" "n+w"
# attr(,"cweight")
# [1] 1 1
```

Comment: Many thanks for fixing this in 2.2-7!